# Erro when i try to delete files/folder in a directory

Tags: vb.net

*When i try to delete folders and files at a specific directory, didn't delete...

My code:*

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    Try

        For Each temp_files In Directory.GetFiles("C:\Windows\Temp")

            File.Delete(temp_files)

        Next

        For Each temp_folders In Directory.GetDirectories("C:\Windows\Temp")

            Directory.Delete(temp_folders)

        Next

        For Each temp2_files In Directory.GetFiles("C:\Users\PEDROA~1\AppData\Local\Temp")

            File.Delete(temp2_files)

        Next

        For Each temp2_folders In Directory.GetDirectories("C:\Users\PEDROA~1\AppData\Local\Temp")

            Directory.Delete(temp2_folders)

        Next

        For Each pref_files In Directory.GetFiles("C:\Windows\Prefetch")

            File.Delete(pref_files)

        Next

        For Each pref_folders In Directory.GetDirectories("C:\Windows\Prefetch")

            Directory.Delete(pref_folders)

        Next

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Sub
```

*Why i cant delete??*

Comment: Try to display the error message, it should answer you why.  Can be permission or file in use

Comment: So...which specific directory are we talking about?

Comment: please post your error message

Comment: An empty try-catch is preventing you from knowing the reason.

Comment: Talking about directory "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp".

I'm not getting any error messages.
When I go to the directory, the files are still there

Comment: Of course you don't get any error messages, the empty `Try/Catch` hides all of them! At least add a message box in `Catch` so that you get informed about the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the delete command only works with an empty directory. to delete everything inside you need a different overload. Also look for permission/ownership issue. And a Try/catch block would help you control the errors you might encounter.

[Look here for the 2 overloads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.delete(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
For Each temp_folders In Directory.GetDirectories("C:\Windows\Temp")

    Directory.Delete(temp_folders, true)

Next
```